# Should tcolorbox enforce inner boxes to be unbreakable?

Tags: tcolorbox

The `tcolorbox` package provides breakable boxes. Also, a `tcolorbox` can be nested inside another `tcolorbox`, even inside a breakable one. But there is no real support for nesting a breakable box inside a breakable box. Breakability is switched off for inner boxes, but it may be switched on again by using the `breakable` key.

In retrospective, this feature (to switch breakability for inner boxes on) has been a permanent pitfall for users, since it's quite easy to misuse the `breakable` key as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{redbox}{colframe=red,enhanced,breakable}
\newtcolorbox{bluebox}{colframe=blue,enhanced,breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{redbox}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{redbox}

\begin{bluebox}
  \begin{redbox}% gives shattered boxes (until tcolorbox 3.04)
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \end{redbox}
\end{bluebox}

\end{document}
```

Therefore, I would like to disable the `breakable` key for inner boxes completely and remove this pitfall.

The only thing which worries me is loss of backward compatibility. That's the reason for this question. Under **very** controlled circumstances, the current feature could have been used to get breakable boxes inside breakable boxes. But to be clear: it's not possible for normal usage.

Is anything speaking against declaring this *feature* a *misbehavior* and therefore remove it?

Comment: Well, that is up to the developer of this nice package :-) No, seriously: I think you have a good reasons to change the semantics of the implementation. The main points to consider is how to deal with backward compatibility: Provide a class-level key that permits users to enable the old behavior, maybe  with in combination with "this deprecated and will be removed in a future version" warnings.

Comment: I had to do something similar in `stackengine` early on concerning the way I defined stacking gaps.  In my case, I was able to employ an `[oldsyntax]` option to provide it the old way.  That way, old code *could* break (because this option would not have already been set in old code), but a quick perusal of the docs would allow the former solution to be restored, while at the same time alerting the user to the new syntax.

Comment: I think you should be able to have a breakable tcolorbox inside a broken footnote in a longtable that's inside an outer tcolorbox, in beamer. All inter-package compatibility issues to be directed to tcolorbox, seems reasonable to me (and the kind of thing longtable users expect to work:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That request reminds me of Churchill's quote at the onset of WWII about Russia: "a riddle wrapped in a mystery inside an enigma".  "Rough times lie ahead," indeed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's a good point. I have to check if such kind of applications would stop working.

Comment: @Daniel That could be done. David Carlisle has brought up a possible failing application which could make me rethink the whole thing.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You are also right. Maybe I can do some kind of `force breakable` key which gives the old behabour...

Comment: I think that just one person using the dangerous "feature" and relying on it for whatever reason is  enough justification for not removing it. Adopting an end user's point of view, having an old document that unexpectedly stops compiling is frustrating and most end users never read documentation so disabling the feature might play against the package. Perhaps leave it as is and mention that its use should be avoid if possible and its not recommended and might produce undesired results; i.e., "use it at you own risk".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Currently, there is such a warning in the documentation. After David Carlisles hint that there ARE thinkable applications for the current implementation and your own comment, I think now that I should leave it as it is and value backward compatibility higher than removing a possible pitfall.

Comment: Which real application did you perceive in Davids Joke? Beside this: looking at your example I would like (if it doesn't exist already) a "breakable-but-not-when-inner" key so that one doesn't have to define a "redbox-outer" and a "redbox-inner" boxtype.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer First, I thought that I may break somebodys applications who deliberately used the feature. David made me think of possible casual combinations with e.g. footnotes which MIGHT transport an inner box somewhere where it could be breakable. I played a little bit around, but currently I do not see a real critical application after all. Your other point: that behavior is exactly the one the change was/is supposed to implement. I know of many users who code like in my example (which seems natural).

Comment: I did understand that you want to implement this behaviour. And imho it is a useful behaviour. So if one doesn't get it by default it should at least be possible to choose through a key or an option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer See my update to the question :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Finally, I'm going to change it, but I add a new key to preserve the old feature. After all, I think no application will notice the change ... yes, never say never ... ;-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Seems like a good plan. Perhaps you could then provide a proper answer to the question?

Comment: I suggest to move the "Update" part into an answer, then. (We do care about our non/answered ratio, you know :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering all the helpful comments, I think it is very unlikely but possible that existing applications could stop working as before, if inner boxes are forced to be unbreakable.

So, the answer to question is: Yes, `tcolorbox` should enforce inner boxes to be unbreakable, but the old behavior should be optionally accessible.

- The next version of `tcolorbox` (3.05 or 3.10) will disable the `breakable` key for inner boxes. I expect that this helps many users avoiding trouble.
- There will be an additional `enforce breakable` key which allows to set inner boxes to be breakable (as in 3.04 or before). This is intended for the unlikely cases where the old behavior is needed.

For the current version 3.04, the following patch can be applied:

```
% insert after tcolorbox v3.04 and the breakable library is loaded
% remove for tcolobox 3.05 or higher
\makeatletter
\def\tcb@layer@inc{%
  \stepcounter{tcblayer}%
  \ifnum\c@tcblayer>1%
    \tcbset{breakable@true/.code=}%
  \fi%
  \ifnum\c@tcblayer>\tcb@managed@layers@max%
    \tcbset{every box on higher layers}%
  \else%
    \expandafter\setbox\csname tcb@footnote@\romannumeral\c@tcblayer\endcsname\box\@mpfootins%
    \csedef{tcb@footnote@cnt@\romannumeral\c@tcblayer}{\the\c@mpfootnote}%
    \tcbset{every box on layer \number\c@tcblayer}%
  \fi%
}

\def\tcb@layer@pushup{%
  \stepcounter{tcblayer}%
  \ifnum\c@tcblayer>1%
    \tcbset{breakable@true/.code=}%
  \fi%
  \ifnum\c@tcblayer>\tcb@managed@layers@max%
    \tcbset{every box on higher layers}%
    \tcbset{every box on higher layers/.code=}%
  \else%
    \tcbset{every box on layer \number\c@tcblayer}%
    \tcbset{every box on layer \number\c@tcblayer/.code=}%
  \fi%
  \addtocounter{tcblayer}{-1}%
}

\tcbset{enforce breakable/.code={%
    \let\tcb@savebox=\tcb@vbox%
    \let\endtcb@savebox=\endtcb@vbox%
    \let\tcb@drawcolorbox=\tcb@drawcolorbox@breakable}}

\makeatother
```

Comment: Above you said that the breakable inner boxes could work under *yery* controlled circumstances. Maybe you could add a check for things which would break? Like, if `\par` would lead to problems, you could redefine `\par` to give an error message inside an inner breakable box. In that case, in some sense the "very controlled circumstances" could be enforced.

Comment: It's really about impossible to get satisfying results, because the computation of available space before break for the inner box will fail and could only be adjusted by hand, if you know where the outer box is positioned on the page. Instead of *very controlled* I should have said *totally unpracticable* ...